# How to add a share button inside a view in Android?

Tags: android, button, android-view, android-dialogfragment, share-button

I need to add a share button to one view inside one of my DialogFragments (Not in the action bar).

Can you give me a clue or a sample maybe? All I could find googling is for action bar (like Sherlok) which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step #1: Put a button inside of your `DialogFragment`.

Step #2: When the user clicks the button, create an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` to share whatever it is you want to share, and call `startActivity()` on it (or, if desired, wrap the `Intent` you create in a chooser `Intent` via `Intent.createChooser()`):

```
  void sendIt(String theMessage) {
    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, R.string.share_subject);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, theMessage);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,
                                       getString(R.string.share_title)));
  }
```